# Android Studio 3.1.2 could'nt create kotlin class(in new menu no option to create kotlin class just java)

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio from 3.0.0 to 3.1.2 and three problems occurred
:
 1. No option for create kotlin class, just option to create java class
 2. No import intellisense - I import everything manual
 3. color of code is gray, just gray and no other color

I searched but nothing useful ...any help or guide thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the problems solved when I closed the AS and opened it again ... Android studio notified me to install kotlin plugin. After I installed it all were ok and the problems went away.